# HighCharts backgroundcolor of group of columns

Tags: highcharts

I'm looking for a way to set the background color of a group of columns in a stacked bar chart.

Our x-axis is showing all months of the past 2 years, but I need a way to visualise the months of 2015 a bit differently than the months of 2016. Instead of having a second x-axis I'd like to set the background colors of the first 12 months to a specific color and the remaining months in another color.

So in the following image everything to the left of the red bar should get a color.

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Yannick

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I was actually already aware of the x-axis its plotbands property, but I never got it to work because I am displaying string values ( Januari, February, etc ).

What does work is the following:

```
xAxis: {
    plotBands:[{
        color: '#FCFFC5',
        from: -1, // 0 isn't correctly filling up the most left column
        to: 11.5 // 11 isn't correctly filling up the december column
    }]
}
```

With the following result:

[image]

Hope it helps somebody in the future.